# SwiftUI - How to size a view relative to its parent when the parent is inside a scrollview?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to dynamically size some views which end up being placed inside of a scrollview. Here is the simplest sample code I can think of:

```
struct RootView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // More views above
                HStack(spacing: 16) {
                    MyView()
                    MyView()
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                // More views below
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
            Image("myImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("Text")
                OtherView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I think really the main issue I'm having is regarding how to dynamically size each `MyView` inside of the `HStack`.

If I wanted the `Image` in `MyView` to be sized to fill its width and grow vertically to maintain its aspect ratio, and then also size each `MyView` in `RootView` to be 40% of `RootView`'s width, what is the best way to accomplish this? I've tried using `GeometryReader` but when it's nested inside the `ScrollView`, it causes the view its used in to collapse in on itself. If I use it outside of the `ScrollView`, I'm effectively always going to be getting the screen width (in this application) which isn't always what I need. On top of that, imagine that `MyView` is nested deeper in the view hierarchy and not called directly from `RootView`, but rather one of its child views. Or better yet, imagine that we don't know that `RootView` doesn't know its rendering a `MyView` if the view is determined at runtime.

To give a little context to anyone who is interested in some backstory, the app I'm trying to build is very modular in nature. The idea is that we really only have one "container view" struct that determines which views to render at runtime. We basically have a `ScrollView` in this container view and then any number of subviews. I'm really struggling with why it seems so difficult to set a view's content dimensions relative to its parent, any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What is the result you're getting with the GeometryReader? Are you using `.padding()` appropriately when using it?

Comment: The result when using `GeometryReader` inside of the `ScrollView` is that the view basically collapses in on itself, and from my reading this seems to make sense with respect to how `ScrollView` and `GeometryReader` sizing works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your goal correctly it is just needed to make images resizable (that makes them fill available space taking into account aspect ratio), like

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
        Image("myImage")
            .resizable()                         // << here !!
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's actually my bad, I'm using `.resizable()` in my actual code, but just forgot to include it in the example. I've updated it now.

With respect to your answer though, I am seeing issues in views where I want the image to take up its available space where the image ends up growing past the bounds of the VStack if they're large. Not sure why that is, but setting the frame manually to something like `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` fixes it (assuming I want it full screen width), but I don't like this solution for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -1):

The best way I can think of is using a `GeometryReader` view. Here is an example.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in 
    RoundedRect(cornerRadius: 5).frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, height: geometry.size.height * 0.8)
}
```

Typically I use the GeometryReader as a "Root" view and scale everything off of it, however you can place it inside of another view or even as an overlay to get the parent view size. For example.

```
VStack {
    GeometryReader { geometry in 
         //Do something with geometry here.
    }
}
```

[Check it out here.](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I mentioned in my question, I've tried using `GeometryReader` already. The issue is that when its used within a `ScrollView` things start to not work so great since the `ScrollView`'s sizing is based on its content and `GeometryReader` is looking to the `ScrollView` for its frame which basically causes everything in that view to collapse in on itself. I've thought about using `GeometryReader` in the root and somehow passing down the proxy object to children, but that would only really work if I always wanted to size relative to the screen width and not any given view